# Is there any reason to use Python threading.local() rather than a ContextVar (in >= 3.7)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-contextvars

Python's [thread-local data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) and [`ContextVar`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/#converting-code-that-uses-threading-local)s appear to achieve the same thing (while having slightly different APIs), with the only user-facing difference being that `ContextVar`s work with async code (coroutines and asyncio), while thread-local data does not.

Is that truly the only practical difference?

Does that mean any code targeting a runtime >= 3.7 (when `ContextVar` was introduced) is better off using `ContextVar` everywhere thread-local data might have been used in the past? Or is there a reason to prefer thread-local data still? (Except for scenarios where you specifically *want* to associate the state with the thread rather than with the context.)

Comment: might be helpful, the second para from [`contextvars docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) "*Context managers that have state should use Context Variables instead of threading.local() to prevent their state from bleeding to other code unexpectedly, when used in concurrent code.*"

Answer (score 2):

The main problem, IMO, is that the "slightly different APIs" are actually huge differences, and while thread.local is straightforward to use, ContextVars present a low-level painful(*), hard to grasp and verbose alternative.

Other than that, ContextVars seem to be the way to go.
I am working on some code to wrap around ContextVars so they can be a drop-in replacement, but the thing is not production ready yet.

If anyone is interested, the project is paused now, lacking some refinement (docs, etc...) for a published package, but it is fully functional at: https://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext/

(*) Ok "painful" is maybe too subjective, but I swear it feels like that, but it  might be because I do not currently have a "real world" use case needing that, and the artificial examples I use are just too artificial grasp the actual use-cases.

Comment: Any update to your wrapper? If it exists, would you be willing to link to it?

Comment: yes.  I got it to the point I needed in the project I am using it, and stopped the development short of a pypi  release.

But it is working in a nice way, and can be installed in any project with pip install -e git://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext.git@0.2b3

Comment: Wow! The decorator/context manager approach is pretty cool! Thanks for sharing!